# How to mark build success when one of the stages is aborted?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile

I've a pipeline with stages where one of the stage, intermittently takes longer than expectation and hence using `timeout` to abort it. But if the stage is aborted, build also marked as aborted. Following is the code for pipeline -

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {

        stage('First') {
            options {
                timeout(time: 10, unit: 'SECONDS')
            }
            steps {
                script {

                    catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS') {
                        echo "Executing stage I"
                        sleep 12
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        stage('Second') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Executing stage II"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even though the stage is marked as `Aborted`, I want to mark build as `Success`. Can you please help how I can achieve this?

Comment: I would really have to play around with this to get it right.  However, I can tell you that you want your `timeout` step inside the script block, and you also want to use `try { } catch { }` instead of `catchError`, and you want to make sure that `timeout` is inside your `try` block.  Finally, you want to make certain you are only catching the exception raised on timeout and not all exceptions so that you don't accidentally mark an actual failed build as successful; you only want to catch the ones that hit the timeout.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44494238/1824868

Answer (score 2):

I answered that question [stackoveflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494238/mark-jenkins-build-as-success-in-case-of-timeout-on-input-declarative-pipelin/60383321#60383321) and I'll post the answer here:

For a Declarative pipeline (not a scripted) you would do something like this

```
stage('Foo') {
      steps {
            script {
                env.PROCEED_TO_DEPLOY = 1
                try {
                    timeout(time: 2, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                        // ...
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    env.PROCEED_TO_DEPLOY = 0
                }
            }
      }
  }
  stage('Bar') {
    when {
        expression {
            env.PROCEED_TO_DEPLOY == 1
        }
    }
    //rest of your pipeline
```

stage "Bar" would be skipped but as for the rest of the stages the job will be marked as passed (assuming nothing wrong happened before).

As for your particular use-case, the trick is to use a try/catch block.